# Querying an authenticated API

Tags: import.io

I am trying to build a web scraper using Import.io. I have the following questions,

1) Is there a way to get data from an authenticated API without knowing its login credentials?

2) Is it possible to get data from a web page that is password protected without login into it?

I basically want to extract data from several pages without it asking me to login every time.

For example, `import.io` won't extract the data of this page - https://github.com/settings/emails because it requires authentication. Is there a way to surpass that.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look.

Comment: So do you have the credentials or not? 1) looks like you don't but 2) looks like you do but are too lazy to wait for the page to log in...?

Comment: I have the credentials. It is a tedious task to login though so I am trying to automate it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.  It requires that you use the login query method (http://api.docs.import.io/#QueryMethods).

Something like;

```
var credentials = {
    username: 'bunnyman',
    password: '*******'
};

// Stuff the cookie into a global (for now)
var cookie;

request.post({
        uri: the_uri_of_the_login_api,
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        json: credentials
    }, function(err, res, body){
        if(err) {
            console.log("error", body);
        } else {
            cookie = body;
        }
    });
```

This will give the cookie back.  Then you can use the _query call (passing in the cookie you got back) Like:

```
   var query = {
    "input": { "some_form_property": "value" },
    "additionalInput": {
        "8d817939-your-api-key-f5dc9502ed72": cookie
    },
    "returnPaginationSuggestions": true
}
request.post({
    uri:  the_uri_of_the_query_api,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    json: query
}, function (error, response, payload){
    if (error){
        console.log(payload);
    } else {
        console.log(payload);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.. if you figure out paging, let me know :)